# How to include Yii framework to custom file

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, yii, yii2

I have a custom file soccer.php that should use models form backend folder. This file is in cron folder and project structure looks like this:

```
- project/
  - backend/
  - cron/

       soccer.php

  - frontend/
  - ...
```

I included models from backend folder like this:

```
use app\models\EventOdds;
use app\models\Events;
```

If I run soccer.php with ubuntu terminal I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "app\models\Events" not found in /project/cron/soccer.php:44
```

How can I include these models and also use Yii functions in my custom file?

Comment: Take a look on the commands and research events that can be run in backgroud: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console

Comment: Also if you use advanced template, models located in the `common\models` folder, Your app  structure does not look like `basic` template